# Is "thenfore" a real word?

Tags: word-usage, archaic-language, error

In this lecture ([15. Petri nets, Basis of The Flow of Tokens](https://youtu.be/1IPOIE0PvQY?t=325)), around 5:25, the lecturer uses the word **thenfore**, I am guessing he is meaning to say **therefore** but misspeaks. However, he is a native speaker and I'm not, so I just wanted to check if this might be is an old, archaic word form that I just didn't know about.

Comment: Nothing I've heard, but you could learn as much from googling it as I could.

Comment: No answer but a few thoughts: no dictionary I checked has it; most, possibly all, of the results on Google are scanning errors for 'therefore'; it seems a strange slip-of-the-tongue speaking error for a native speaker to make; maybe it is a jargon word in this particular topic; that the words are actually 'then forgetting' (<not true, but I thought it for a moment); that the OP's question is not really about English language learning. 
Until you find some other explanation, assume that he mean 'therefore' and made an unexplainable slip-of-the-tongue mistake.

Comment: Do you think he might be saying "thenceforth" ("from this time forward")? I listened to the audio but can't tell from the context if "thenceforth" makes sense. I checked the O.E.D. and "thenfore" is not a word. "Thenceforth" is the closest.

Answer (score 1):

I watched the video. The instructor just misspoke, he meant "therefore" as you guessed. "Thenfore" is not a word.

[Etymologically](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/therefore), therefore = there + for, with the [archaic meaning](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/there#Pronoun) of "there" as "that", which also shows in words like thereat, thereunder. So therefore = for that (reason). Assuming a similar etymological development, "thenfore" would mean "for then", which sounds pretty odd.